# How do I get Artifactory to serve as a Docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I want Artifactory to be a Docker registry.  I am trying to follow the directions [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-UsingDockerCompose-1MinuteSetup.1).

When I update the /etc/default/docker file, I cannot restart the Docker service.  I get an error when I try to restart the Docker service.

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Looking into this error did not help me.  Therefore I try to get around this issue by not modifying this file.

When I try this command "docker login docker.artifactory" I get this:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.artifactory/v1/users/: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, not docker.artifactory
```

I therefore tried this command " ".  But that results in this:

```
Error response from daemon: Login: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
} (Code: 404; Headers: map[Server:[Artifactory/5.11.0] X-Artifactory-Id:[fc560f4748814da2:18461899:1635019eb47:-8000] Date:[Fri, 11 May 2018 20:15:27 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json]])
```

I am running Ubuntu 16, Docker 1.13.1, and Artifactory version 5.11.  I can log into Artifactory from the GUI running in a Docker container.  I cannot get Artifactory to work as a Docker registry despite trying to follow the directions on two different Linux distributions.

My second attempt involved trying to start over deploying Artifactory with docker-compose to be a Docker registry on a CentOS server.  But this also fails.  For reasons that are unclear to me, the three Docker containers that are supposed to support the registry (Postgres, Artifactory and Nginx) remain in the status "Restarting."  I cannot get the Artifactory web UI to work properly on CentOS.

I have tried many things to get the directions to work for me.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I get Artifactory to be a docker registry?

Comment: You must edit the docker-opts to allow docker.artifactory as insecure, like the instructions tell you. Because you did not, then you get the x509 error. Please edit the file, then show the systemctl status like the error message says so we can see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The modification you made to /etc/default/docker probably included a syntax error, that's why Docker didn't start. To find the reason why it didn't start, you should have look at the output of "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe".

I'd rather go with your second approach and not modify the /etc/default/docker, but issue a real certificate instead. Go to letsencrypt.org and issue a wildcard certificate to artifactory.your.domain and *.artifactory.your.domain, then set up your Docker registry using the domain method.

And your probably don't need a v1 registry unless you have an explicit reason for it. Try `curl -L -u ... https://artifactory.your.domain/v2/_catalog` to check whether your registry works. 404 errors like the one above indicate a misconfigured reverse proxy.

My config looks as follows. This allsows my to reach artifactory at artifactory.my.domain, the docker registries at WHATEVER.artifactory.mydomain and my virtual docker registry called 'docker' at docker.my.domain to get a nice name ;)

```
server {
    listen [2a01:...]:443 http2;
    listen ...7:443 http2;
    server_name artifactory.my.domain;
    include tls.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url https://artifactory.my.domain;
        include proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://.../artifactory/;
    }
}

server {
    listen [2a01:...]:443 http2;
    listen ...:443 http2;
    server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.artifactory.my.domain docker.my.domain;
    include tls.conf;

    if ($repo = '') {
        set $repo docker;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url https://artifactory.my.domain;
        include proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://.../artifactory/api/docker/$repo$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Where tls.conf is as follows to get an a+ rating at ssllabs.com:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/.../fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/.../privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam               dhparam.pem;
ssl_ecdh_curve            secp384r1;
ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#ssl_ciphers               'EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:!AES128';
#ssl_ciphers               'EECDH+AESGCM';

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="Vjs8r4z+80wjNcr1YKepWQboSIRi63WsWXhIMN+eWys="; pin-sha256="YLh1dUR9y6Kja30RrAn7JKnbQG/uEtLMkBgFF2Fuihg="; pin-sha256="sRHdihwgkaib1P1gxX8HFszlD+7/gTfNvuAybgLPNis="; max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;


ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
```

And proxy.conf is as follows:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_cookie_path  ~*^/.* /;
proxy_read_timeout  900;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```